# How do I reference the detailViewController on an iPad that is using a splitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I setup a project on XCode 4.3 and IOS 5 without using storyboards for both iPhone and iPad using the default Master/Detail setup from the create new project dialog.

The iPhone side works just fine.  I select an option in the tableView and the detailViewController screen updates with the new information based on the selection.

My implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
        Shapes *currentShape = [self.shapesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {  
            if (!self.detailViewController) {  
                self.detailViewController = [[[GeoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeoDetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];  
            }  
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];  
            [self.detailViewController populateDisplay:currentShape];  
        } else {  
            [self.detailViewController populateDisplay:currentShape];  
        }  
}
```

However, when I run on the iPad, self.detailViewController does not exist. so the display doesn't update.  I can still see it on the iPad screen, I just can't change anything on it.  How do I reference it in the code so I can make changes to what is displayed?

Comment: So you want to get a pointer to the detail view controller of a split view controller?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was puzzled by the templates implementation of the Master/Detail view.  I asked a similar question:

[How to update DetailView using MasterDetail Application Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931848/how-to-update-detailview-using-masterdetail-application-template)

You can use the detailItem (id - so you can pass in a reference) property that is set up by default for the DetailViewController class.

Comment: Doh!  The fix is so simple.  In the delegate that instantiates both the master and detail view controllers, I simply assign the masterViewController.detailViewController property at that time.  I can then use it elsewhere since I am always updating the same detail view depending on the selection from the tableView.  Your thread pointed me in this direction so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to the split view controller itself, you can do:

```
[(GeoDetailViewController *)[[(UINavigationController *)[[splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] populateDisplay:currentShape];
```

To get the pointer to your split view, you will probably have to go via your app delegate:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] splitViewController];
```

(assuming that you are using the default split view controller template - YMMV depending on how you have implemented it)

Note that when you create your split view, you **must** set the detail view controller to be a `GeoDetailViewController` - if you are not and you cannot for app design reasons, I can edit my answer to work around that.

Comment: The detail view controller is a GeoDetailViewController as far as I can see, but your solution doesn't work as it crashes with [UINavigationController populateDisplay:] unrecognized selector sent to instance ... But why does it say UINavigationController in the error?

Comment: When the viewControllers array is setup in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, location 1 is set to the detailNavigationController, not the detailViewController I am looking for.  I therefore need to somehow get to the detailViewController from the detailNavigationController.

Comment: So I found the answer by looking in location 0 of the viewControllers array of the returned detailNavigationController.  It seems to work, but just wondering if this is a robust answer.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Answered my own question.  This is not a robust way to find the detailViewController as it only works on an iPad with 5.0 on it.  Earlier versions of IOS crash because it doesn`t find the detailViewController.  So I`mm still looking for a definitive answer.

Comment: Is the *split view's* detail view controller a navigation controller then?

Comment: I can't get enough information in these comments.  The split view detail controller is setup using:

Comment: GeoDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[GeoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeoDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

Comment: self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

Comment: That's the change I made that gets it working on IOS 5.0 but it crashes on all earlier versions because those controller arrays are not setup.  I have therefore implemented the (so simple I must be stupid) alternative of setting up the masterViewController.detailViewController variable when the detail view is instantiated in the delegate.  I am therefore giving the tick to the other solution which is what pointed me in that direction.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: If it is crashing, that implies that there is something fundamentally wrong with your implementation (not my code). What does it say when it crashes????

Comment: No, your code is good, but only for IOS 5.0.  In previous versions, the viewControllers array at the second level (where you dig out index:0) doesn't exist.  I think the problem is in the template code generated by XCode that doesn't seem to care about older versions of IOS.

Answer (score 1):

In the master/detail template, Apple uses the following code in the MasterViewController (i.e. the one on the left):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.detailViewController = (MYDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
```

With the property on MasterViewController defined as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MYDetailViewController *detailViewController;
```