# Master View Controller -> Detail View Controller Communication

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, master-detail

Is there a possibility for access to the array defined in Master View Controller from Detail View Controller? 
I have a Master-Detail Application in xCode. In Master View Controller an Array is defined. In Detail View Controller there are detail informations according to one entry from this array.

Is it possible to get access from Detail View Controller to the array and update them?

How can I pass the reference to the array from Master to Detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any link whatsoever between your Master and Detail view?

If so, then you can expose access to the array via making it a "`@property`" of the Master View Controller that you can access from the Detail view controller.

[Here is a related question with answers that may help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134275/how-do-i-reference-the-detailviewcontroller-on-an-ipad-that-is-using-a-splitview).  I can't give you more specific answers than this because you haven't said how you've set up your Master <-> Detail View Controller implementation.

Comment: here is an example: [link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-4294356/Simple_SplitView_Controller_Example.zip.html) How can I delete entries from array?